# Sort An Array in Objective C with Multiple Items

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Yeah there Post of them but none of them working for me , i  need to Sort a Multidimentional Array , 
This is my Array Looks Like

```
(
{
    FileDate = "2014-02-21T19:08:50Z";
    FileName = "Cyber";
    FileSize = 65;
    FileURL = "Inciden.pdf";
},
    {
    FileDate = "2014-02-21T19:08:47Z";
    FileName = "Products";
    FileSize = 64;
    FileURL = "Plan.pdf";
},
    {
    FileDate = "2014-02-21T19:08:36Z";
    FileName = "Network";
    FileSize = 70;
    FileURL = "cPlan.pdf";
},
```

)

its the simple NSArray * Fulldata ;
Now can anyone tell me a Best Way to Sort it .

Comment: Post your code showing how you have tried to sort this. And explain how the array should be sorted.

Comment: Btw, this is not a multidimensional array, but an array of dictionaries.

Comment: And please show the other posts you found by searching and explain why they don't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to sort on date...

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [FullData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"FileDate" ascending:NO]];
```

That should do it.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable answer, based on the assumption that the OP wants to sort based on date. There are lots of ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You posted a dump of an array of dictionaries. There are a number of methods that will let you sort an array in different ways.

I'm partial to the block-based methods like sortedArrayUsingComparator (for immutable arrays) or sortUsingComparator (for sorting mutable arrays in place).

Both of those methods take a comparator block which compares 2 objects from the array and decides which one should be first, returning either NSOrderedDescending or NSOrderedAscending for each comparison.

The system then sorts the array by asking your block of code to compare pairs of objects.

You could also use the methods that uses sort descriptors (e.g. `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`) The descriptor based methods are a better choice if you need to sort using multiple keys (e.g. sort an array of names based on last name, then first name within last name, and then by age within first name.)

In order to help you sort your array we need to know what criteria you want to use to sort it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't using NSComparator going to be much slower as it would be akin to an Insertion Sort and could have O(n^2) time whereas an NSSortDescriptor should deliver O(n log n) or O(n) on a dictionary?

Comment: @smyrgl Why do you think different algorithms are used? The only difference is how each pair of values is compared during the sorting.

Comment: Well that's why I asked it more as a question but using NSComparator means you are going to traverse the array in a classic Insertion Sort and check a pair of items against one another to see whether they move up or down and thus will get moved one over and Insertion Sorts have a worst case of quadratic time.  With an NSSortDescriptor on a key of an NSDictionary though its akin to a Bucket Sort and should be possible in linear time.  I have tested this when sorting an NSCountedSet with NSDictionary  and it is quite a bit faster (but again I'm not the authority on this).

Comment: @smyrgl, you're wrong. The specific sort algorithm is under the control of the OS, and can be optimized at runtime. In my experience it's performance is O(n log n) or better, suggesting to me that the OS usually suggests an algorithm like quicksort.

Comment: Hmmm...here is the results of a document scanner using the technique I mentioned with NSSortDescriptor.  Let me run it with NSComparator as well but this is clearly linear time.  10 books
2014-05-05 12:52:27.852 TGDocumentScanner[46242:303] Total time 0.560867
2014-05-05 12:52:27.853 TGDocumentScanner[46242:303] Average time per 10000 char 0.000711

1000 books
2014-05-05 12:51:52.557 TGDocumentScanner[46148:303] Total time 51.536115
2014-05-05 12:51:52.557 TGDocumentScanner[46148:303] Average time per 10000 char 0.000717

Comment: What is a "TGDocumentScanner"? The OP wants to sort an in-memory array. Sorting other types of content will have different results. I believe the Core Data sorts work best with sort descriptors, since those can take advantage of the hashing that Core Data does, but that's not the problem we're solving here.

Comment: This is a log file from something I wrote that is using an in-memory array.  I ran the same thing with NSComparator and did get nearly the same results with NSComparator (it's a little slower but clearly not O(n^2)) so you are correct, point conceded.  I was just asking a question though, I don't think it deserved a downvote but to each their own.

Comment: I didn't down vote you. To the contrary, I up voted your answer, because it is a perfectly valid solution to the OPs question.

Comment: Mea culpa, and thanks for correcting me on NSComparator as there are a lot of situations where it is easier to implement than an NSSortDescriptor.

Comment: @smyrgl It seems someone is needlessly down voting all answers to this question. Sadly, some people seem to think it is appropriate to down vote good answers to bad questions.

Comment: The sorting time depends on how array elements are compared, but also on whether the array is already sorted or partially sorted. In the latest versions, all the sorts check whether an array starts and ends with a long sequence of elements in ascending order or in descending order, and in that case performs the sorting a lot faster than the typical n log n. As a result, if you try method A and then method B sorting in exactly the same order, method B will always appear faster because it sorts an array that is already sorted, so be careful with benchmarks.

Comment: @gnasher729, your comment makes it sound like you have insight into the internals of Apple's sort algorithms. Where are you getting your information?